# Display row number using {{#each}}

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to count each row in a table. Each table row is a new collection. The code below counts the total number of collections and displays that. How do I change it to display the row number.

Path: `calc.js`

```
SalaryCalculator: function () {
    return SalaryCalculator.find({});
},
SalaryCalculatorCount: function () {
    return SalaryCalculator.find({}).count();
}
```

Path: `calc.html`

```
{{#each SalaryCalculator}}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{SalaryCalculatorCount}}</th>
        <td>{{specialisation}}</td>
        <td>{{subSpecialisation}}</td>
        <td>{{positionTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{yearsOfExperience}}</td>
        <td>{{salary}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Just use `@index` in your template. Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225071/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-array-in-a-meteor-template-each-loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's the  helpers

```
SalaryCalculator: function () {
    var count = 1;
    var salCalDetails = SalaryCalculator.find({});
    salCalDetails.forEach(function(doc){
         doc.rowCount = count;
         count++;
    });
    return salCalDetails;
},
```

---

```
{{#each SalaryCalculator}}
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{rowCount}} </th>
    <td>{{specialisation}}</td>
    <td>{{subSpecialisation}}</td>
    <td>{{positionTitle}}</td>
    <td>{{yearsOfExperience}}</td>
    <td>{{salary}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Or if you follow through the answer given by @Michel Floyd then you need this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103990/3422755 as `{{@index}}` will give you starting number as 0