# How to print index+1 in a table with #each loop on hbs file using Node js

Tags: node.js, hbs

I want to put the serial no. in the table inside the #each loop, In the .hbs file I tried this:

```
{{#each item}}
    <tr>
        <th>{{@index}}</th>
    <tr>
{{/each}}
```

But this prints the index from 0, I want to start it from 1, How do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding offset to {{@index}} when looping through items in Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103989/adding-offset-to-index-when-looping-through-items-in-handlebars)

Answer (score 0):

a helper function that lets you perform calculations on expressions like addition and subtraction etc.

Below function registers a new helper, which simply increments a value by 1:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper("addOne", function(value, options)
{
    return index + 1;
});
```

You can then use it within the handlebar expression using the addOne keyword, like:

```
{{addOne @index}}
```